# Android: if this then change menu?

Tags: android, eclipse, if-statement, menu

I want the options menu and its functions to change when I command it to.

So for example: layout is Fullscreen, options and quit. When I click on fullscreen, I want the menu to change so that it now looks like: Exit Fullscreen, options, quit.

I dont know everything in coding yet so I hope you can give some example code.

Thanks in advance!

this is the code for the menu:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {

     getMenuInflater().inflate (R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }



    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) 
        {

            case R.id.help:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, help.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            break;

            case R.id.exitfullscreen:
                finish();  
            break;

            case R.id.quit:
                 moveTaskToBack(true);
            break;



            default:    
            break;
        }
        return false;
```

Comment: what does your menu code look like?

Comment: added menu code. I succeeded in adding the menu option, but it doesnt do anything when clicking it. I cant find a menuItem to replace with my 'exitfullscreen' so i cant give it a function.

Comment: Instead of inflating an xml of menu items in `onCreateOptionsMenu`, do it via code. I'll quickly write an example

Comment: Inflate the menu based on the state? So if the app is in fullscreen then inflate the fullscreen menu etc.

Comment: Yes , I did that now, So exit fullscreen works, but it also has the option exit fullscreen when in fullscreen, and I find that ugly + I would love to find out how to change that. I can add a menuitem but it doesnt have a function then... Doomsknight did you make a code?

Comment: @Ahmad sounds like an idea. Yea. Just have two seperate xml menus. and load them accordingly. Eclipse is still loading lol :|

Answer (score 1):

Following your comments try this:

in your fullscreen.java

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {

     getMenuInflater().inflate (R.menu.menu, menu);
        MenuItem mu = menu.findItem(R.id.exitfullscreen);
        mu.setTitle("Exit Full Screen");
        return true;
    }
```

P.S. Apply this where and when necssary to change your menu items text (title).

Comment: I thought override didnt work in xml?! At least it says it doesnt understand why the text is there.

Comment: @Bart ths goes it your code. not xml Replace your `onCreateOptionsMenu` method

Comment: Ye thanks, but it doesnt recognize if(inFullscreen) , do you know why? Is it a command or something? (i used the second way)

Comment: @Bart inFullScreen is a boolean value, you would need to detect or know what mode it is, and replace this to say if its in full screen or not. As well as with the IDs. Define each one at the top of your activity, with different int values. e.g. `int FullScreen_ID = 101;`

Comment: Hey, how do I detect in what mode it is?

Comment: I just copied the code in the fullscreen.java, and it already has detection of fullscreen? Do you know why eclipse doesnt recognize it? Please help me D:

Comment: Man now my code is messed up and you ignore me, you are so mean D:

Comment: @Bart :o I was driving home. Takes me an hour. If you have two seperate classes, one for full screen and one not, remove the if statement, and just add the 1 relevant Menu item. Then do the same on other file with the other menu item. You are essentially adding menu items. So add the ones you want, in the files you want, with the text you want.

Comment: @Bart try that code, it will change the menu item in question, from your menu xml.